# Power BI - Get last month from last year

Tags: filter, powerbi

I have this table:

| Year | Month | Agency | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 9 | 1 | 233 |
| 2019 | 9 | 4 | 132 |
| 2019 | 8 | 3 | 342 |
| 2020 | 3 | 2 | 321 |
| 2020 | 3 | 4 | 34 |
| 2020 | 5 | 2 | 56 |
| 2020 | 5 | 4 | 221 |
| 2020 | 5 | 1 | 117 |
| 2018 | 12 | 2 | 112 |
| 2018 | 12 | 2 | 411 |
| 2020 | 4 | 3 | 241 |
| 2020 | 4 | 2 | 155 |

I'd like to set a new measure/column where last month from last year is 1, and 0 in another cases:

| Year | Month | Agency | Value | Filter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 9 | 1 | 233 | 0 |
| 2019 | 9 | 4 | 132 | 0 |
| 2019 | 8 | 3 | 342 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 2 | 321 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 4 | 34 | 0 |
| 2020 | 5 | 2 | 56 | 1 |
| 2020 | 5 | 4 | 221 | 1 |
| 2020 | 5 | 1 | 117 | 1 |
| 2018 | 12 | 2 | 112 | 0 |
| 2018 | 12 | 2 | 411 | 0 |
| 2020 | 4 | 3 | 241 | 0 |
| 2020 | 4 | 2 | 155 | 0 |

I've been able to "copy" a new table with values from Month=5 and Year=2020 ("the lastest from the lastest"):

```
TableData - Last Charge = 
   var table = FILTER(
      TableData,
      AND( 
         MAX('TableData '[Year])='TableData '[Year],
         MAX('TableData '[Month])='TableData '[Month]
      )
   )
return SUMMARIZE(table , TableData [Year], TableData [Month], TableData [Agency], TableData [Value])
```

However, my intention is don't create new tables and use measures/columns tu use it like FILTER when I create a graphic.

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this measure:

```
Measure =
VAR a =
    MAX ( 'Table'[Year] )
VAR b =
    MAX ( 'Table'[Months] )
VAR c =
    MAXX ( ALL ( 'Table' ), [Year] )
VAR d =
    MAXX ( FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), [Year] = c ), [Months] )
RETURN
    IF ( a * 100 + b = c * 100 + d, 1, 0 )
```